# WIA Scanner Large Image Size

Tags: c#, image, winforms

I am trying `WIA` to acquire images from a scanner with C#. I am using a `PictureBox` to acquire images. I am able to scan images. But size of image is too large. How i can set resolution of the image and show this image to Fixed size that can be fit within the form. Where Form WindowState is Maximum.

I am using this code on Button Click to get image from Scanner.

```
try
{
 //get list of devices available
 List<string> devices = WIAScanner.GetDevices();

     foreach (string device in devices)
     {
         lbDevices.Items.Add(device);
     }
     //check if device is not available

    if (lbDevices.Items.Count == 0)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Attach a Scanner Device.");
    }
    else
    {
       lbDevices.SelectedIndex = 0
    }
    //get images from scanner
    List<Image> images = WIAScanner.Scan((string)lbDevices.SelectedItem);

    foreach (Image image in images)
    {
         pic_scan.Image = image;
         pic_scan.Show();
         pic_scan.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.AutoSize;

         //save scanned image into specific folder
         image.Save(@"D:\ABC.jpeg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
     }
}
catch (Exception exc)
{
    MessageBox.Show(exc.Message);
}
```

Thanks for kind response.

Comment: `PictureBox` and `System.Drawing.Image` are WinForms, not WPF. Sure you tagged your question correctly?

Comment: @Clemens, Corrected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom to have the image fit properly in a PictureBox.

```
pic_scan.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;
```